# Does Drop index invalidate the packages immediately or next time when they ran?

Tags: sql, db2

I am working on dropping for index, i wanted to understand how the drop index works for DB2 database, doesn't invalidate all the package in which sql refer the index being drop immediately during the drop index execution or will it invalidate the package when they next that package is used.

Here i have read something like invalidate of package. Does it really means invalidating package or something to do with the execution plan which are saved in cache memory of that particular SQL which is referring to the index which is being dropped.

Could someone explain what is exactly happens and what that means.

Thanks

Comment: no one has answered this question because no one knows what you mean by package.  What do you mean by package?

Comment: What version/platform of DB2? Do you mean pre-compiled SQL packages and the execution plans impacted by dropped indexes?

Comment: @data_henrik : yes I was referring to the pre-complied SQL packages and execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking are the "dependent" packages on the index invalidated. The answer is yes. DB2 invalidates it so that, next time its hit, an implicit compile is done and the entry in catalog cache is refreshed.

In DB2, stored procs have packages, dynamic queries have to be bound to packages ( if you run a dynamic query, you'll see something like NULLID.SYSSH200 which is a CLI package ).

Hope this helps.

Thanks